# Items inside the statusbar don't stretch to the maximal width

Tags: c#, wpf

I added a grid inside the statusbar to have two columns, the statusbaritems have the maximal width but the items inside them(the text and the progressbar) do not. I tried to resolve that by adding

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

but it doesn't work.

```
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Name="txtNotificator" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <ProgressBar Name="downloadProgress" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by using

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```

instead of

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```